# Can Ajax URL be a PHP function?

Tags: php, ajax

Sorry if this is too basic or has been authoritatively answered somewhere which has eluded me.

I'm getting started with Ajax and PHP. I'm working with some buttons on my page and each of which needs to look up some data from a SQLite db and gets rendered on the page one way or another.

My question is that instead of having a .php page for each button how can I have each Ajax call hit a single .php page but reference a function to run, inside which I would inspect/process the contents of the POST?

Is this possible? If so how? I have tried using syntax like:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions.php?func=writeMsgAdd",
            data: { "contentid": contentID },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("foobar: " + data );                    
            }
        });
```

Where the page is functions.pho and that page contains a function called writeMsgAdd() But no luck. Would appreciate any insight into how to achieve this.

Comment: If you parse the _GET arg into a function call within your functions.php... yup. Just be extra careful, and make a whitelist of function names, and sanitize your _GET args.

Comment: You're posting to functions.php, so use $_GET within your functions.php page.

Comment: I don't agree that you need to use GET --  Just put your data in the POST instead of the end of the URL .. `data: {"phpFunction":"writeMsgAdd", "contentid": contentID },`

Comment: @Zak that doesn't really add anything, just moved the function name from `$_GET` to `$_POST`

Comment: No one said he had to use GET ;) It was just in his example. I would personally put it along with the other POST args, just for readability. Since combining GET and POST in one call just makes my mind go 'messy!'.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [simple PHP router](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router). There's also [klein](https://github.com/klein/klein.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ajax` call should look something like the below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions.php",
    data: { "phpFunction":"function1", "contentid": contentID },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("foobar: " + data );                    
    }
});
```

And your php file should look something like the below:

```
$function = $_POST["phpFunction"] ;

if ($function == "function1") {

    //Code for function 1 goes here
}
else if ($function == "function2" {
    //Code for function 2 goes here
}
....
```

> Updated

The above way, you are sending only 1 value to the `ajax response`, if you want to send more than one variable you can add `dataType: json` to your ajax, and then in the `php` you must return a json value.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: json
    url: "functions.php",
    data: { "phpFunction":"function1", "contentid": contentID },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Val1: " + data.key1);
        console.log("Val2: " + data.key2);                    
    }
});
```

And your php function must end with:

```
echo json_encode(array("key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2")) ;
exit() ;
```

Comment: Why keep both the `func` `$_GET` parameter and `phpFunction` `$_POST` parameter?

Comment: My bad, I will remove it!

Comment: @MarioA.Rawady

Yes, your solution makes a lot of sense. I will accept as answered as soon as Stack Overflow permits me to.

Many thanks for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Check the updated answer, if you are interested in sending more than 1 variable to the response of the ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a massive if else if statement on the server side, you can do this, assuming that you are passing writeMsgAdd as the name of a function and contentid as the argument that you want to pass to writeMsgAdd:

Client Side

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions.php",
        data: { 
            "func": "writeMsgAdd",
            "contentid": contentID 
        },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log("foobar: " + data );                    
    }
});
```

Server Side:

```
<?php 
    $func = $_POST["func"] ;
    $contentid = $_POST['contentid'];
    call_user_func($func, $contentid);
?>
```

Or, if you want to pass multiple different parameters to each function, then I would use call_user_func_array instead:

Client Side

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions.php",
        data: { 
            "func": "writeMsgAdd",
            "args": JSON.stringify({"contentid": contentID})
        },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log("foobar: " + data );                    
    }
});
```

Server Side:

```
<?php 
    $func = $_POST["func"] ;
    $args = json_decode($_POST['args'], true);
    call_user_func_array($func, $args);
?>
```

Comment: That is very elegant and idiomatic. I love it! I'll be attempting to use this approach. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem!  As noted before, be sure to only allow functions from your whitelist, and as always use prepared statements for the sql.

Comment: You could add as well `function_exists();` to help matters with the whitelist too. Might be redundant, but its to help prevent fatal execution errors. I like this answer better than a giant IF block.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple functions that all take different arguments, then instead of passing contentid by itself, I would instead pass one variable that would be a json array of key-value pairs that you want to pass to the function, and then on the server side, you could use call_user_func_array instead of call_user_func.  The difference is that call_user_func takes individual arguments, whereas call_user_func_array takes an associative array as its argument.

Comment: Also, you might want use this as well, to check if func and args exist in your post request: if (!array_key_exists('func', $_POST) or !array_key_exists('args', $_POST)) { exit;